# Getting a separate page count per chapter

Tags: epub, mobi, kobo

With the ebooks I generate myself (using [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html)), I have a single page count for the entire book.

Ebooks that I purchase off the Kobo store have a separate page count for individual chapters, which is handy for books (should I carry on reading or just go to sleep?) and even more attractive for short story collections. It's an effect I'd like to replicate in my own ebooks.

I understand that Kobo uses its own custom ['kepub'](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Kepub) format, an extension of epub 2. Is what I want possible with vanilla epub? Preferably in such a way as will work on a range of devices, and that will 'stick' when run through kindlegen.

Comment: How does knowing that you are on page X of a chapter help you in determining if you should continue reading? Does it also show a total of pages for the chapter (X of Y)? Or does that pagecount count down?

Comment: @Anthon It shows 'page 4 of 20' (or whatever), so it gives an idea of how long there is to go in the current chapter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kobo ereaders have two different reading engines, one for `.epub` files, another for `.kepub.epub` files.
These two engines have some little differences, one is the way page count is displayed: for the entire book with `.epub`, for a single chapter with `.kepub.epub`.
If you want to use this feature the simplest way is to rename the file extension, but it is advisable to use Calibre instead. If you install the *Advanced Kobo Driver* plugin it will automatically convert `.epub` files in `.kepub.epub` when you send them to the device, while performing some optimizations that you won't have if you simply change the extension.
And, this is a feature of the reading device, not of the file itself: it's not coded in your ebook, it's the ereader that has it and use it when detects the file type: you won't get it in other devices even if you change the extension.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for there to be a standard way of doing this, but a straight 'no' is the next-best thing. Ah, well.

Comment: Ah, finally I got per chapter page count working for my Kobo Forma and my Epubs, thank you!